# Another multiplication in homotopy groups of simplicial loop space

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-homotopy-groups

So, I'm trying to fill up the details in some of the propositions of Goerss and Jardine's book, "Simplicial Homotopy Theory". On [Lemma 7.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH0ly.png), I've tried to do something similar to what we do in the case of topological spaces (usually using stuff about $H$-spaces), but I'm having trouble describing the second multiplication $\star$ mentioned in the proof.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered MathOverflow?